# definition of stochastic diferential equation

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

What is mean by: $X_Y(t)$ satisfies the stochastic differential equation
$$
dX_Y(t) = \sigma X_Y(t) dW(t).
$$
What is definition of $dX_Y(t)$ and $dW(t)$?

Comment: Have you at least looked at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation#Use_in_probability_and_mathematical_finance) ?

Comment: yes, but they use the notation without explanation

Comment: They don't. The Wikipedia article refers you further to [Ito calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus). Learning that is doable but not just a matter of explaining notation.